# Не получается вызвать функции, которые лежат внутри функции

Tags: javascript, jquery, framework

Решил для себя понять простой принцип работы *jQuery* и столкнулся с проблемой. При попытке организации упрощенной версии библиотеки у меня не получается вызвать функции, которые лежат внутри функции. Пример кода:

```
var jQ = function(el) {
   this.el = document.getElementById(el);
}

jQ.prototype.html = function(text){
  this.el.innerHTML = text;
  return this;
}

jQ.prototype.css = function(key, value){
  this.el.style[key] = value;
  return this;
}

// Использование 
jQ('bar').html('test');
```

Comment: вы сделали функцию конструктор, но используете ее как обычную функцию, не надо так. перед вызовом добавьте `new`: `new jQ('bar').html('test');`

Answer (score 1):

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype
    Child.prototype = new F()
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype
}

// создали базовый класс
var parent = function() {};

// создали класс
// и сделали его потомком базового
var jQ = function(el) {
   this.el = document.getElementById(el);
}
extend(jQ, parent);

// добавили в класс parent методы и свойства
parent.prototype.html = function(text){
    this.el.innerHTML = text;
    return this;
};   
parent.prototype.css = function(key, value){
    this.el.style[key] = value;
    return this;
};



// Использование 
var element = new jQ('bar');
element.html('test');
```

Более подробно про наследование вы можете почитать:

https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance

http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance

Comment: а при чем там наследование, если в вопросе просто `new` забыли

Comment: @Grundy, Да, я в курсе, но есть проблема =). А если хочу с многими элементами работать, как в jquery. Чтобы поменять селектор, нужно постоянно создавать объект через new?

Comment: @АлексейФурсов, ага, если посмотрите саму функцию jQuery - увидите что она как раз объект и возвращает, каждый раз

Comment: @Grundy, Насколько я понимаю, в jQuery код следующий: `$('.element').css('width');   $('.element2').css('width');`. А у меня выходит `$ = new Jq('.element1');  $.css('width');  $ = new Jq('.element2'); $.css('width')`

Comment: @АлексейФурсов, это тема отдельного большого вопроса :-) в двух словах: `function jQuery() { return new jQuery.fn.init(); }` поэтому ее и вызывают без `new`

Comment: @Grundy, не составило бы труда поправить мой код или кинуть на источник. но лучше код поправить ;-).

Comment: @АлексейФурсов Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34567/discussion-between-grundy-and--).